# Get reference to Thread Object from its ID

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How can I get reference to a Running Thread if I know the ID associated with that Thread?

**e.g.**

```
long threadID = 12342;
Thread thread = (What goes here?) getThreadFromId(threadID); //I know this is totally made up
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do it.
Both are quite simple:

- Old way: get the root thread group you may access `Thread.currentThread().getGroup()`..getParent() in loop. and call `enumerate(Thread[])`
- newer (slower though). `for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) if (t.getId()==id)...`

The first method has a small problem that due to a bug in `ThreadGroup.destroy()`, a ThreadGroup may not enumerate anything at all.

The second is slower and has a security flaw, though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the security flaw?

Comment: this answer was posted nearly 8.5 years ago. Java has changed quite a bit in that time. Is there a better answer now at least in the Java world that is not limited to Android?

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code in order to get the Thread Name (For e.g. I want to get names of Threads that are in deadlock )

```
ThreadMXBean threadMB = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long threadIds[] = threadMB.findDeadlockedThreads();
for (long id : threadIds) {
     System.out.println("The deadLock Thread id is : " + id
                            + "  > "
                            +       
     threadMB.getThreadInfo(id).getThreadName());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the Android API does not include java.lang.management.

Comment: This doesn't work not only be cause Android doesn't include `java.lang.management`. This doesn't work because it doesn't give you a reference to the `Thread`