# Function to obtain a thread given its ID

Tags: java

Is there a way to get a thread from its ID in Java?

Comment: congratulations. you are the first to ask a question in non-English!

Comment: The question is in French. Translated in English.... Hi! is there a mean to get a thread after his ID? for example: I have the id 15, is there a function in Java that allows me to get the thread ID 15? Many thank you ..

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6668121/1977828) helps?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions have to be in english here


Comment: Now that it's translated, it's a fair question. Too quick to downvote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get reference to Thread Object from its ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667496/get-reference-to-thread-object-from-its-id)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such provision in Java, but it is easy enough to implement it yourself: each time you create a new thread and give it an ID, add it to a `Map<String, Thread>`. Then you can look up your thread there.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get an id, is from the `Thread` so I would just keep the thread if that is what you want, and not use the id to look anything up.

Note, you can get all the threads e.g. `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` and search for the id. However, I would write the code so you never need to do this.